# Nondeterministic State Machine understanding

Tags: dsl, state-machine, finite-automata, non-deterministic

I am trying to build a DSL for my iOS project. 
For this I plan to build a `Semantic Model` in a form of a `State Machine`. (The terminology is from Fowler's book on DSLs). 
The main idea: `State Machine` is coded as the set of `states` and `transitions` between them, and then some unit tests can be written to check if `some_action` on `some_state1` leads the system to a `some_state2`. 

The problem is my app has a lot of background threads, so more than one state can be active in State Machine at a given moment.

I've read that such State Machines are `Nondeterministic finite automaton`, skimmed through wiki page, but that looks too theoretical for me.

Here is an example state machine:

`s8` can be activated only when it received `t7` and  `t8`, that means it should "wait".

[image]

The questions:
1. Is there something like `"wait"` in state machines? 
2. Maybe, this is not NFA, but two state machines? Should I care how to name this kind of semantic model at all? 
3. Is it OK to `s8` be implemented with some background thread, which accepts notifications from `s4` and `s7`, and is activated only when both of them sent notifications (this means that the unit test fail when timeout is reached, and then that timeout should be mentioned somewhere in a model) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [orthogonal regions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UML_state_machine#Orthogonal_regions) in a hierarchical state machine, this should do what you are looking for.

Create a new state with two child regions: the first region containing s1, s2, s3, s4 and a new final state (the target of t8); the second region containing s5, s6, s7 and a new final state (the target of t7). Then add a new transition from the new state to s8.

The new transition should only be traversed when both regions are in a final state.

Comment: Thanks, this model is very practical, and it answers all my sub-questions.